# Get SymbolInfo from identifier of type declared outside parsed source

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I want to use Roslyn to parse C# code, and I want to get the qualified name of every referenced type in the code.

Say for example I want to parse this snippet of code:

```
using System;

namespace RoslynTest
{
    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            String a = "Hello, World!";
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

To parse it, I use the following code:

```
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);

CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("test", new[] { tree });
SemanticModel semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree, false);

CompilationUnitSyntax root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();

IEnumerable<IdentifierNameSyntax> identifiers = root.DescendantNodes()
    .Where(s => s is IdentifierNameSyntax)
    .Cast<IdentifierNameSyntax>();

foreach (IdentifierNameSyntax i in identifiers)
{
    SymbolInfo info = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(i);

    if (info.Symbol == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown :(");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(info.Symbol.ContainingNamespace?.Name + "." + info.Symbol.ContainingType?.Name + "." + info.Symbol.Name);
    }
}
```

In this example, when I get to the IdentifierNameSyntax that describes "String", info.Symbol will be null. I would like some way to know the full name System.String, and the same with other types referenced.

- How can i get SymbolInfo from an IdentifierNameSyntax for a type declared outside the parsed source?
- Is there a way to construct a SemanticModel from the using statements?

Comment: Use `.OfType<T>()`, and use `info.Symbol.ToString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual problem is that there is no `String` type.

If you look at the compilation errors in your SemanticModel, you'll see an error to that effect.

You need to add a reference to mscorlib in your `Compilation` so that `System.String` exists.
Once you do that, `info.Symbol` will not be null.

Comment: Thank you, I added:
`MetadataReference reference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(string).Assembly.Location);`
and that solves my example. Is there any practical way to create MetadataReferences from all the using statements?

Answer (score 0):

Plus, just cut to the chase as:

```
IEnumerable<IdentifierNameSyntax> identifiers = 
root.DescendantNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>();
```

rather than:

```
IEnumerable<IdentifierNameSyntax> identifiers = root.DescendantNodes()
    .Where(s => s is IdentifierNameSyntax)
    .Cast<IdentifierNameSyntax>();
```